# Lagging/Slow/Framerate drops MacBook Pro 13' mid 2014

Tags: memory, ssd, macbook, macbook-pro, lag

I bought a used MacBook Pro Retina mid 2014, and I have installed VENTURA via OpenCore Legacy.

The MacOS often freezes. Simple operations lead take considerable time to load, and its nearly impossible to watch content in 4K, on CHROME or VLC.

I've already reset PRAM and SMC. And the same problem was with BigSur installed instead of Ventura.

I have also run a hardware analysis (by software), and it reported no problems.

SSD check also came with good results, even better than the test I ran on my GAMING PC.

The thing is, I've tested some PC with old INTERL cpu, no dedicated GPU, 8gb RAM, that the system ran smoothly, with just a good SSD.

My question is this, what else can I try? What can be the cause of the lagging?

Here goes a quick video just browsing on the machine, to show you the lagging: https://youtu.be/rWhB1wfNoL8

EtreCheck Report

> EtreCheckPro version: 6.8.1 (68024) Report generated: 2023-04-16 14:47:52 Download EtreCheckPro from https://etrecheck.com Runtime:
> 3:53 Performance: Good
>
> Problem: Computer is too slow Description:  Everything is slow, from
> logging in to opening apps to typing. As an e xample, trying to launch
> an app from the dock might take 10 seconds be fore it even responds.
>
> Major Issues:   Anything that appears on this list needs immediate
> attention.    No Time Machine backup - Time Machine backup not found.
> System Integrity Protection disabled - System Integrity Protection is
> disabled. This computer is at risk of malware infection.   Apple
> security disabled - Apple security software is disabled. This computer
> is at risk of malware infection.   Obsolete hardware - This computer
> may be considered obsolete.
>
> Minor Issues:   These issues do not need immediate attention but they
> may indicate future problems or opportunities for improvement.    SSD
> too slow - SSD is showing poor performance.   Heavy RAM usage - Apps
> are using a large amount of RAM.   Apps crashing - There have been
> numerous app crashes.   Apps with heavy CPU usage - There have been
> numerous cases of apps with heavy CPU usage.   Unsigned files - There
> are unsigned software files installed. These files could be old,
> incompatible, and cause problems. They should be reviewed.   Kernel
> boot arguments - This computer has custom kernel boot arguments.
>
> Hardware Information:   MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)
> Status: Obsolete   MacBook Pro Model: MacBookPro11,1   2,6 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5 (i5-4278U) CPU: 2-core   8 GB RAM - Not
> upgradeable
> BANK 0/DIMM0 - 4 GB DDR3 1600
> BANK 1/DIMM0 - 4 GB DDR3 1600     Battery: Health = Normal - Cycle count = 298
>
> Video Information:   Intel Iris - VRAM: 1536 MB
> Color LCD (built-in) 2880 x 1800
>
> Drives:   disk0 - APPLE SSD SD0128F 121.33 GB (Solid State - TRIM:
> Yes)    Internal PCI 5.0 GT/s x2 Serial ATA
> disk0s1 - EFI (MS-DOS FAT32) [EFI] 210 MB
> disk0s2 [APFS Container] 121.12 GB
> disk1 [APFS Virtual drive] 121.12 GB (Shared by 6 volumes)
> disk1s1 - M*******************s (APFS) [APFS Virtual drive] (55.37 GB used)
> disk1s2 - Preboot (APFS) [APFS Preboot] (1.85 GB used)
> disk1s3 - Recovery (APFS) [Recovery] (1.15 GB used)
> disk1s4 (APFS) [APFS Container] (9.30 GB used)
> disk1s4s1 - M***********D (APFS) [APFS Snapshot] (9.30 GB used)
> disk1s5 - Update (APFS) (1 MB used)
> disk1s6 - VM (APFS) [APFS VM] (1 MB used)
>
> Mounted Volumes:   disk1s1 - M*******************s [APFS Virtual
> drive]
> Filesystem: APFS
> Mount point: /System/Volumes/Data
> Used: 55.37 GB
> Shared values
> Size: 121.12 GB
> Free: 53.33 GB
> Available: 59.78 GB
>
> disk1s2 - Preboot [APFS Preboot]
> Filesystem: APFS
> Mount point: /System/Volumes/Preboot
> Used: 1.85 GB
> Shared values
> Size: 121.12 GB
> Free: 53.33 GB
>
> disk1s4s1 - M***********D [APFS Snapshot]
> Filesystem: APFS
> Mount point: /
> Read-only: Yes
> Used: 9.30 GB
> Shared values
> Size: 121.12 GB
> Free: 53.33 GB
> Available: 59.78 GB
>
> disk1s5 - Update
> Filesystem: APFS
> Mount point: /System/Volumes/Update
> Used: 1 MB
> Shared values
> Size: 121.12 GB
> Free: 53.33 GB
>
> disk1s6 - VM [APFS VM]
> Filesystem: APFS
> Mount point: /System/Volumes/VM
> Used: 1 MB
> Shared values
> Size: 121.12 GB
> Free: 53.33 GB
>
> Network:   Interface bridge0: Thunderbolt Bridge   Interface en0:
> Wi-Fi
> 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac
>
> System Software:   macOS Ventura 13.3.1 (22E261)    Time since boot:
> Less than an hour   Boot args: keepsyms=1 debug=0x100
> ipc_control_port_options=0 -nokcmismatchpanic amfi=0x80
>
> Security:   Gatekeeper: App Store and identified developers   System
> Integrity Protection: unknown (Custom Configuration)
>
> Antivirus software: None!
>
> Unsigned Files:   Launchd: /Library/Internet
> Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist
> Command: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Java
> Updater.app/Contents/MacOS/Java Updater -bgcheck
> Details: Exact match found in the legitimate list - probably OK
>
> Launchd: /Library/Internet
> Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist
> Executable: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Helper-Tool
> Details: Exact match found in the legitimate list - probably OK
>
> Launchd: /Library/LaunchAgents/com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist
> Command: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Java
> Updater.app/Contents/MacOS/Java Updater -bgcheck
> Details: Exact match found in the legitimate list - probably OK
>
> Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist
> Executable: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Helper-Tool
> Details: Exact match found in the legitimate list - probably OK
>
> Plugin: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
>
> Preference panel: /Library/Internet
> Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/deploy/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
> Preference panel: ~/Library/PreferencePanes/Perian.prefPane
>
> Apps: 1
>
> Applications:   448 apps   16 x86-only apps   3 unsigned apps
>
> System Extensions:   [Not Loaded] AdBlockVPNMacOSProvider - version
> 2.0.1 (App Store - 2023-03-08)
> Application: /Applications/AdBlock.app - version 2.0.1 (Adblock Inc. - 2023-04-12)
>
> System Launch Daemons:   [Not Loaded]  41 Apple tasks   [Loaded]  198
> Apple tasks   [Running]  149 Apple tasks   [Other]  One Apple task
>
> System Launch Agents:   [Not Loaded]  23 Apple tasks   [Loaded]  195
> Apple tasks   [Running]  177 Apple tasks   [Other]  One Apple task
>
> Launch Daemons:   [Not Loaded] com.adobe.ARMDC.Communicator.plist
> (Adobe Inc. - installed 2021-11-11)
> Executable: /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.adobe.ARMDC.Communicator
>
> [Not Loaded] com.adobe.ARMDC.SMJobBlessHelper.plist (Adobe Inc. -
> installed 2021-11-11)
> Executable: /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.adobe.ARMDC.SMJobBlessHelper
>
> [Loaded] com.google.keystone.daemon.plist (Google LLC - installed
> 2023-04-14)
> Executable: /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/MacOS/GoogleSoftwareUpdateDaemon
>
> [Not Loaded] com.logi.ghub.updater.plist (Logitech Inc. - installed
> 2023-04-13)
> Executable: /Applications/lghub.app/Contents/MacOS/lghub_updater.app/Contents/MacOS/lghub_updater
>
> [Loaded] com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper.plist (Microsoft
> Corporation - installed 2023-04-13)
> Executable: /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper
>
> [Not Loaded] com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist (Not signed -
> installed 2023-04-12)
> Executable: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Helper-Tool
>
> Launch Agents:   [Not Loaded]
> com.adobe.ARMDCHelper.cc24aef4a1b90ed56a725c38014c95072f92651fb65e1bf9c8e43c37a23d420d.plist
> (Adobe Inc. - installed 2023-04-12)
> Executable: /Library/Application Support/Adobe/ARMDC/Application/Acrobat Update
> Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Acrobat Update Helper
>
> [Loaded] com.dortania.opencore-legacy-patcher.auto-patch.plist
> (Mykola Grymalyuk - installed 2023-04-11)
> Command: /Library/Application Support/Dortania/OpenCore-Patcher.app/Contents/MacOS/OpenCore-Patcher
> --auto_patch
>
> [Loaded] com.google.keystone.agent.plist (Google LLC - installed
> 2023-04-14)
> Command: /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent
> -runMode ifneeded
>
> [Loaded] com.google.keystone.xpcservice.plist (Google LLC -
> installed 2023-04-14)
> Command: /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent
> -runMode xpchost
>
> [Not Loaded] com.logi.ghub.plist (Logitech Inc. - installed
> 2023-04-13)
> Command: /Applications/lghub.app/Contents/MacOS/lghub_system_tray --background
>
> [Loaded] com.microsoft.update.agent.plist (Microsoft Corporation -
> installed 2023-04-13)
> Command: /Library/Application Support/Microsoft/MAU2.0/Microsoft AutoUpdate.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Update
> Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Update Assistant
> --launchByAgent
>
> [Not Loaded] com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist (Not signed -
> installed 2023-04-12)
> Command: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Java
> Updater.app/Contents/MacOS/Java Updater -bgcheck
>
> User Login Items:   [Not Loaded] LaunchAtLoginHelper (App Store -
> installed 2023-04-12)
> Modern Login Item
> /Applications/AdBlock.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/LaunchAtLoginHelper.app
>
> [Not Loaded] BatteryHealthHelper (App Store - installed 2023-04-15)
> Modern Login Item
> /Applications/Battery Health.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/BatteryHealthHelper.app
>
> [Not Loaded] StartUpHelper (Spotify - installed 2023-03-27)
> Modern Login Item
> /Applications/Spotify.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/StartUpHelper.app
>
> [Not Loaded] LaunchAtLogin (Serhiy Mytrovtsiy - installed
> 2023-04-15)
> Modern Login Item
> /Applications/Stats.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/LaunchAtLogin.app
>
> [Not Loaded] WhatsApp Login Helper (App Store - installed
> 2023-04-15)
> Modern Login Item
> /Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/WhatsApp Login Helper.app
>
> [Not Loaded] AppCleaner SmartDelete (Julien Ramseier - installed
> 2023-04-14)
> Modern Login Item
> ~/Downloads/AppCleaner.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/AppCleaner SmartDelete.app
>
> App Extensions:   Safari extensions:
> AdBlock Icon - /Applications/AdBlock.app
>
> Plugins:
> aetsce - /Applications/tokenadmin.app
>
> Widgets:
> Battery Health - /Applications/Battery Health.app
>
> Notification providers:
> NotificationService - /Applications/Prime Video.app
>
> File providers:
> Google Drive - /Applications/Google Drive.app
>
> Finder sync extensions:
> FinderSyncExtension - /Applications/Google Drive.app/Contents/Applications/FinderHelper.app
>
> Ad-blockers:
> AdBlock Engine - /Applications/AdBlock.app
>
> QuickLook Previews:
> EtreCheckQuickLook - ~/Downloads/EtreCheckPro.app
> com.etresoft.etrecheck4 *.etrecheck
>
> Internet Plug-ins:   JavaAppletPlugin: Java 8 Update 361 build 09 (? -
> installed 2023-04-12)
>
> 3rd Party Preference panels:   Java (? - installed 2023-01-09)
> Perian (? - installed 2023-04-15)
>
> Backup:   Time Machine Not Configured!
>
> Performance:   System Load: 2.58 (1 min ago) 2.39 (5 min ago) 2.88 (15
> min ago)   Nominal I/O usage: 0.47 MB/s   File system: 27.70 seconds
> Write speed: 266 MB/s   Read speed: 728 MB/s
>
> CPU Usage Snapshot:   Type Overall   System: 4 %   User: 5 %   Idle:
> 91 %
>
> Top Processes Snapshot by CPU:   Process (count) CPU (Source -
> Location)   WindowServer 12.34 % (Apple)   EtreCheckPro 7.82 %
> (Etresoft, Inc.)   kernel_task 4.12 % (Apple)   nsurlsessiond (2) 1.84
> % (Apple)   com.apple.WebKit.WebContent (11) 1.34 % (Apple)
>
> Top Processes Snapshot by Memory:   Process (count) RAM usage (Source
>
> - Location)   com.apple.WebKit.WebContent (11) 2.13 GB (Apple)   EtreCheckPro 788 MB (Etresoft, Inc.)   kernel_task 339 MB (Apple)
>   MTLCompilerService (12) 165 MB (Apple)   AppleSpell 160 MB (Apple)
>
> Top Processes Snapshot by Network Use:   Process (count) Input /
> Output (Source - Location)   nsurlsessiond 7 MB / 346 KB (Apple)
> mDNSResponder 694 KB / 193 KB (Apple)   apsd 9 KB / 73 KB (Apple)
> rapportd 41 KB / 38 KB (Apple)   com.apple.WebKit.Networking 33 KB /
> 28 KB (Apple)
>
> Top Processes Snapshot by Energy Use:   Process (count) Energy (0-100)
> (Source - Location)   WindowServer 6 (Apple)   nsurlsessiond (2) 2
> (Apple)   photolibraryd 1 (Apple)   cloudd (2) 1 (Apple)   bluetoothd
> 0 (Apple)
>
> Virtual Memory Information:   Physical RAM: 8 GB
>
> Free RAM: 30 MB   Used RAM: 5.35 GB   Cached files: 2.62 GB
>
> Available RAM: 2.65 GB   Swap Used: 0 B
>
> Software Installs (past 60 days):   Install Date Name (Version)
> 2023-04-12 macOS 13.3.1 (13.3.1)   2023-04-12 Kit de Depuração do
> Kernel (1.0.0.0.1.1680373477)   2023-04-12 AutoPkg-Assets (1.0)
> 2023-04-12 MRTConfigData (1.93)   2023-04-12 XProtectPlistConfigData
> (2167)   2023-04-12 XProtectPayloads (95)   2023-04-12 Java 8 Update
> 361 (1.8.361.09)   2023-04-12 Adobe Acrobat Reader (Continuous)
> (23.001.20143)   2023-04-12 AdBlock (2.0.1)   2023-04-12 Prime Video
> (9.32)   2023-04-13 Microsoft Edge (112.0.1722.39)   2023-04-13
> Microsoft AutoUpdate (4.58.23040900)   2023-04-13 Lightshot Screenshot
> (2.22)   2023-04-13 Disk Speed Test (3.4.2)   2023-04-14 Microsoft
> OneDrive   2023-04-14 Google Drive (1.3.18.216)   2023-04-15 Battery
> Health (6.1)   2023-04-15 WhatsApp (2.2316.6)
>
> Diagnostics Information (past 7-30 days):   2023-04-16 02:35:59
> WindowServer High CPU Use
> Executable: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer
>
> 2023-04-15 21:17:38 MTLCompilerService Crash (88 times)
> Executable: /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/MTLCompilerService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/MTLCompilerService
>
> 2023-04-15 19:54:35 AMPLibraryAgent Crash
> Executable: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPLibrary.framework/Versions/A/Support/AMPLibraryAgent
>
> 2023-04-15 00:57:15 uTorrent Web.app High CPU Use (2 times)
> Executable: /Applications/uTorrent Web.app
>
> 2023-04-14 01:24:06 mediaremoted Crash (50 times)
> Executable: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/Support/mediaremoted
>
> 2023-04-14 01:18:06 AirPlayXPCHelper Crash (54 times)
> Executable: /usr/libexec/AirPlayXPCHelper
>
> 2023-04-14 01:17:29 VLC.app High CPU Use
> Executable: /Applications/VLC.app
>
> 2023-04-13 00:23:26 ControlCenter Crash (25 times)
> Executable: /System/Library/CoreServices/ControlCenter.app
>
> 2023-04-12 23:43:18 App Store Crash
> Executable: /System/Applications/App Store.app
>
> 2023-04-12 22:50:05 photoanalysisd High CPU Use (2 times)
> Executable: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/Support/photoanalysisd
>
> 2023-04-12 21:19:21 ContinuityCaptureAgent Crash (2 times)
> Executable: /usr/libexec/ContinuityCaptureAgent
>
> End of report

Comment: Well… you have an unsupported system, so it's not expected to be able to run Ventura, but what is likely not helping at all is you seem to have inherited some dangerously old plugins with it - [Perian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perian) should have been uninstalled years ago, I'd say you need a clean install with no migration for starters.

Comment: Or you may try any mainstream desktop Linux. Any are safe and updated, the opposite of obsolete OS versions.